# Perform Speech-to-Text in Python using pre-transcribed text as guide

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I'm working on a python application that's meant to align video clips based on what actors are saying on screen.

As an example, I have a scene where actors are reading dialogue from a script. They do the 3min scene 10 times.

I am currently transcribing what they say using speech-to-text, but because the actors are reading the same dialogue repeatedly, I want to use the pre-transcribed dialogue (the movie script) to help guide the speech-to-text engine to be more accurate.

For example:
"Are you telling me you built a time machine out of a Delorean?"

Speech to text returns:
"Are you talking me you building a time machine out of a daylight?"

I should be able to figure out where the mistakes are and estimate the correct line using the original script and lock everything against the movie script.

I'm currently using CMUSphinx in Python to get my STT data and it works very well.  But I'm having some trouble with the logic on this next part.

I'll post some code shortly!

EDIT: Discovered that the search term I was looking for is "audio aligner" and "long audio aligner."  These seem to be tools included in some STT packages.  CMUSphinx in particular may have the ability to do this built in.  Exploring that.